# invalid BigNumber value for Date

Tags: ethers.js, react, typescript

I tried to update the current campaign based on Id, target value and a new date, but getting an error when executing the function

function from contract

```
   function updateCampaign(
        uint _id,
        uint _newTarget,
        uint _newDeadline
    ) external {
        Campaign storage campaign = s_campaigns[_id];

        if (campaign.owner != msg.sender) revert CrowdFund__NotOwner();
        if (campaign.status != CampaignStatus.REVERTED)
            revert CrowdFund__Required();
        if (block.timestamp > campaign.deadline) revert CrowdFund__Deadline();

        campaign.target = _newTarget;
        campaign.deadline = _newDeadline;

        emit UpdatedCampaign(_id, _newTarget, _newDeadline);
    }
```

from my react context

```
type updateForm = {
  pId: number;
  target: ethers.BigNumber;
  deadline: Date | string | number;
};

  const updateCampaign = useCallback(
    async (updateForm: updateForm) => {
      const signer = accountProvider?.getSigner();
      const contractWithSigner = contract?.connect(signer);

      try {
        const updateId = await contractWithSigner?.updateCampaign(
          updateForm.pId,
          updateForm.target,
          updateForm.deadline
        );
        return updateId;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
    [contract, accountProvider]
  );
```

from my react page

```
interface FormProps {
  pId: number;
  target: string;
  deadline: Date;
}

type ExtendCampaignModalProps = {
  pId: number;
  target: number;
  deadline: string;
  closeModal: () => void;
};

const ExtendCampaignModal = ({
  pId,
  target,
  deadline,
  closeModal,
}: ExtendCampaignModalProps) => {
  const { updateCampaign } = useCrowdFundData();
  const { account } = useAccount();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [form, setForm] = useState<FormProps>({
    pId: pId,
    target: "",
    deadline: new Date(),
  });
  const handleFormFieldChange = (
    fieldName: string,
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [fieldName]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleExtendCampaign = async () => {
    if (!account) return;
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await updateCampaign({
        pId: form.pId,
        target: form.target,
        deadline: new Date(form.deadline),
      });
      closeModal();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }

return (
  <div>
     <FormField
      labelName="New End Date *"
      placeholder="End Date"
      inputType="date"
       value={form.deadline}
       handleChange={e => {
       handleFormFieldChange("deadline", e);
        }}
      />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap w-1/2 justify-between mt-5 gap-[10px]">
        <CustomButton
         btnType="button"
         title="Extend My Campaign"
         styles="w-full bg-[#374151] hover:bg-[#4acd8d] transition-all ease-out duration-300 mb-2"
         handleClick={handleExtendCampaign}
        />
  </div>
)
```

The error log is

Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value="2023-05-25T00:00:00.000Z", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deadline is of type `Date` but it should be converted to timestamp before sending the transaction.

I think you can do it here

```js
        const updateId = await contractWithSigner?.updateCampaign(
          updateForm.pId,
          updateForm.target,
          updateForm.deadline.getTime()
        );
```

`.getTime()` shouls convert it to a timestamp number.

Comment: Thank you ser.. can see it working now :)